# Formation control for ground vehicles

Tags: swarm

I am working on a project where I am aiming at connecting multiple vehicles in a formation and allowing *hive* control of the formation. The robots (*husky-like*) use ROS and so I was hoping to incorporate as much ROS functionality as possible. Specifically, I am looking at using ROS2 for its peer-to-peer nature.

I have conducted a quick literature review on the project and have found a lot of papers (primarily on UAVs). Unfortunately, they have not released the source as I can see. One particular paper I found interesting is [Distributed Multi-Robot Formation Splitting and Merging in Dynamic Environments](http://www.alonsomora.com/docs/19-zhu-icra.pdf). I was hoping someone could push me down the correct path to some adaptable formation control algorithms?

Another concept I have come across is `distributed consensus` which as I understand is a mutual decision across the network on some algorithm. Can anyone provide me links to better understand how this is achieved (I believe this would be valuable given ROS2 is peer-to-peer).

Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help. I understand this is more of an information grab than a support question but I am interested in hearing some discussion around the topic from people who have experienced it.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Grant Dare. Adding a 'thanks' section to a question is not required, we all tend to be thankful for the people helping us, and expect other people to be thankful too, so saying it just adds noise to the question and distracts people from the problem posed. It may seem counter intuitive, but excessive politeness can itself be impolite, as giving people extra text to read, even if they ignore it, is disrespectful of their time.